# Is having the sum of each column zero a sufficient condition for a matrix to be singular?

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have a square matrix,

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        a_{1,1} & \ldots & a_{1,n} \\
        \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
        a_{n,1} & \ldots & a_{n,n} \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Is a sufficient condition for the matrix to have determinant zero that

$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_{i, k}=0 \space\forall\space k$$

If so, can we produce a clear proof why?

(If not, can we make it a sufficient condition by strengthening the condition to include that only the main diagonal contains negative terms?)

Comment: My inspiration for this question was my observation that the transition matrices for Markov processes that I was working with always had an eigenvalue 1. I'd be happy to see counter-examples, though - I'm not 100% sure that my conjecture is correct.

Comment: Yes, because it means that the columns are linearly dependant.

Comment: @Taladris: more directly, it means that the _rows_ are linearly dependent: the bottom one is minus the sum of the others.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh: Yes, you're right. I read "the sum of columns is zero" instead of "the sum of each column".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the determinant must be zero.

**Proof 1:**
Since the sum of each column is zero, the sum of all the *rows* is the zero vector.  Hence the rows are not linearly independent, and the determinant is zero.

**Proof 2:**
Notice that the transpose of the matrix ($A^T$) sends the vector $v = (1,1,1,\ldots,1)$ to the zero vector.  Therefore, $A^Tv = 0v$, and $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A^T$.  Since the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues, the determinant of $A^T$ (and hence the determinant of $A$) is zero.

**Proof 3:** Induction on $n$.
The base case is trivial.
For the inductive step, first add the top row of the matrix $A$ to the second row, making it so that the sum of the $2$nd through $n$th values in any column are zero.  Then evaluate the determinant by row-reduction across the top row, and notice that each cofactor is zero since the $n-1 \times n-1$ submatrix has determinant zero (by the induction hypothesis).

Comment: Are you sure it's $Av = 0$ and not $vA = 0$? Just take the transpose anyway.

Comment: Ah good point. ${}{}$